# How to parse a JSON key nest using RapidJSON

Tags: c++, json, parsing, rapidjson

I'm using RapidJSON to parse an incoming JSON file, I can iterate and get the value through the different nests. I mean the variable values (i.e.: protocolVersion = 2). But I cannot get the start of a nest { : }. Using the following JSON as an example:

```
{
   "header":{
      "protocolVersion":2,
      "messageID":2,
      "stationID":224,
      "data": 
           {
           1:
           2:
           3:
           }
   },
}
```

I want to parse "header" and "data". I'm using this line but it doesn't match as a parse way

```
ItsPduHeader_t& header = message->header;
```

And trying this, I get an error:

```
ItsPduHeader_t& header = doc["header"].GetObject();


error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘ItsPduHeader_t&’ {aka ‘ItsPduHeader&’} from an rvalue of type ‘rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >::Object’ {aka ‘rapidjson::GenericObject<false, rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> > >’}
  381 |     ItsPduHeader_t& header = doc["header"].GetObject();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 overloaded methods in [source code](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/blob/0ccdbf364c577803e2a751f5aededce935314313/include/rapidjson/document.h#L1629) of RapidJSON:

```
Object GetObject() { RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(IsObject()); return Object(*this); }
ConstObject GetObject() const { RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(IsObject()); return ConstObject(*this); }
```

And all of them return object by value. You should try to define `header` like simple object (not reference) or const reference to object.

**Update**

Your json is not correct at first. You can't get `ItsPduHeader_t` from RapidJSON simple types directly. You should get RapidJSON object representation for `header` and then for `data` and query it:

```
const char* json = "{\"header\":{\"protocolVersion\" : 2,\"messageID\":2,\"stationID\":224,\"data\":{\"foo\":\"bar\"}}}";
rapidjson::Document d;
d.Parse(json);

for (const auto& m : d["header"]["data"].GetObject()) {
    std::cout << m.name.GetString() << " " << m.value.GetType() << std::endl;
}

const auto& header = d["header"];
const auto& data = header["data"];

std::cout << "header->data->foo: " << data["foo"].GetString();
```

Comment: I don't understand it. In the example, protocol version value is got using protocolVersion = doc[protocolVersion].GetInt(), however, I don't know how to integrate them in my code. Using those methods is: `header GetObject() { RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(IsObject()); return header(*this); }` Is it correct?

Comment: I move those errors, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64839622/why-i-receive-error-while-compiling-rapidjson