# Why I receive error while compiling RapidJSON

Tags: c++, json, parsing, rapidjson

Using RapidJSON for parsing a JSON file, I get these errors.

This is part of the JSON file:

```
{
   "header":{
      "protocolVersion":2,
      "messageID":2,
      "stationID":224
   },
   "cam":{
      "generationDeltaTime":37909,
      "camParameters":{
         "basicContainer":{
            "stationType":5,
```

This is the code

```
 doc.Parse(pr);   
           
  
    const auto& header = doc["header"];

    header.protocolVersion = doc["header"]["protocolVersion"].GetInt();   
    header.messageID = doc["header"]["messageID"].GetInt(); 
    header.stationID = doc["header"]["stationID"].GetInt(); 

    
    const auto& cam = doc["cam"];
    
    
    cam.camParameters.basicContainer.stationType = doc["cam"]["camParameters"]["basicContainer"]["stationType"].GetInt();
     
    const auto& referencePosition = doc["cam"]["camParameters"]["basicContainer"]["referencePosition"];
```

I get this error. I don't know what it says they have no member.

```
 In member function ‘void MqttApplication::sendm(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’:
.cpp:389:12: error: ‘const class rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ has no member named ‘protocolVersion’
  389 |     header.protocolVersion = doc["header"]["protocolVersion"].GetInt();
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mqtt_application.cpp:390:12: error: ‘const class rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ has no member named ‘messageID’
  390 |     header.messageID = doc["header"]["messageID"].GetInt();
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
mqtt_application.cpp:391:12: error: ‘const class rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ has no member named ‘stationID’
  391 |     header.stationID = doc["header"]["stationID"].GetInt();
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
mqtt_application.cpp:402:9: error: ‘const class rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ has no member named ‘generationDeltaTime’
  402 |     cam.generationDeltaTime = doc["cam"]["generationDeltaTime"].GetInt();
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mqtt_application.cpp:405:9: error: ‘const class rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ has no member named ‘camParameters’
  405 |     cam.camParameters.basicContainer.stationType = doc["cam"]["camParameters"]["basicContainer"]["stationType"].GetInt();
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Claiming that your problem is "why I receive error parsing JSON" indicates that you successfully compiled something that parses JSON, but it has some kind of a problem running. Yet, the above shows a bunch of compilation errors, which means that nothing was compiled, executed, or parsed anything, JSON, or not. If you are asking about this compilation error, can you explain exactly what you believe this `header` object is, that the shown code expects to have members like `protocolVersion`, and others, that are resulting in these errors?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, how much code should I show for not being confusing? The code says those variables are not member of the structure, however, as indicated in the input JSON, they exist

Comment: Stackoverflow lists the requirements for a [mre]. Furthermore, input JSON is utterly meaningless. Are you expecting RapidJSON to return a class whose members have names that come from the JSON file? That is un-possible. C++ does not work this way, on its core, fundamental level. You must be misunderstanding something in the documentation. Can you post a link which claims that `rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >`, that `parse()` returns, has ***any*** of these fields?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, parse() returns a JSON string, however, I want to get all variable values. As far as I know this should be the way of getting all the required values. Individually, I could get the values using printf

Comment: I'm sure there is a away of getting all the variable values. But it is necessary to research the library's documentation in order to determine how to do that. Trying to write random code in C++ and then see if it works is unlikely to accomplish much of anything. Especially when the attempt violates fundamental rules of C++. In C++  it is impossible to read some kind of a file and always return a class with members whose names will always be the same as the data in the file. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I assure you I got all variables printed correctly and the code compiled well. I've added the "branch" const and it was there when my code crashed. To understand why it happened was my goal for asking these question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header` is object of `rapidjson::Value` type and doesn't have `protocolVersion`, `messageID` and `stationID` members. You should provide your custom object type to store values from `header`. The same goes for other variables (`cam` and `referencePosition`). For example:

```
struct MessageHeader
{
    int protocolVersion;
    int messageID;
    int stationID;
};

//...

const auto& header = doc["header"];

MessageHeader messageHeader;
messageHeader.protocolVersion = header["protocolVersion"].GetInt();
messageHeader.messageID = header["messageID"].GetInt();
messageHeader.stationID = header["stationID"].GetInt();

std::cout << "message header protocol version: " << messageHeader.protocolVersion << std::endl;
```

Comment: I get this error: error: `expected ‘;’ before ‘header’
  388 |     header header;
      |           ^~~~~~~
      |           ;  `However, it is written `header header;` after the `const`

Comment: It is an example. You should substitute it with your own structure.

Comment: So, should I insert the whole JSON structure and create a whole struct type as the example?

Comment: No. Do you try to use object type from your previous question `ItsPduHeader_t` instead of `MessageHeader`?

Comment: Yes, I was using header instead of MessageHeader. How works with multiple level of struct? Like this: `struct MessageCam
    {
       int X;
       struct MessageCamParameters
       {
   struct MessageBasicContainer
   {
      int X;
      struct MessageReferencePosition
      {
         int X;
         int X;
         struct MessagePositionConfidenceEllipse
         {
            int X;
            int X;
            int X;
         };
         struct MessageAltitude
         {
            int X;
            int X;
         };
      };
   };  ...`

Comment: I get this error when executing the code: `/usr/include/rapidjson/document.h:1053: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::operator[](const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, SourceAllocator>&) [with SourceAllocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted`  Could be because of the & present in const?